# Postgresql simple query very slow response time

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-performance

I have a really simple database that I am using to build out some JSON for Elasticsearch. I'm the only person connected to the database, and only using it for this specific task. Anyway, hitting some tables on the database is incredibly slow, so slow that it will take months to build out the Elasticsearch index I am working on. I've looked at all the articles regarding Postgresql tuning, etc, and nothing I'm changing is fixing the issue. The query that I am doing, as you can see below in the EXPLAIN ANALYZE portion, is a very simple query, with no joins or anything else, and it's still very slow. I'm just trying to figure out what I can do to speed this up, because I see no reason for this to be so slow.

Here's all the relevant information I can think of, if anything more is needed, I can add.

**System Specs**

```
[root@pgdb ~]# free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:         61444      39416      22027        458          8      38531
-/+ buffers/cache:        876      60568
Swap:            0          0          0


[root@pgdb ~]# cat /proc/cpuinfo
processor   : 0
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 62
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2670 v2 @ 2.50GHz
```

**All Tables**

```
cotitsk=# \d+
                          List of relations
 Schema |       Name       | Type  |  Owner   |  Size   | Description
--------+------------------+-------+----------+---------+-------------
 public | company          | table | postgres | 1838 MB |
 public | company_industry | table | postgres | 1621 MB |
 public | company_title    | table | postgres | 3837 MB |
 public | industry         | table | postgres | 224 kB  |
 public | industry_skill   | table | postgres | 446 MB  |
 public | industry_title   | table | postgres | 1229 MB |
 public | interest         | table | postgres | 344 MB  |
 public | skill            | table | postgres | 438 MB  |
 public | skill_skill      | table | postgres | 21 GB   |
 public | title            | table | postgres | 1841 MB |
 public | title_interest   | table | postgres | 2799 MB |
 public | title_skill      | table | postgres | 27 GB   |
 public | title_title      | table | postgres | 11 GB   |
(13 rows)
```

**Schema of Table Being Queried**

```
cotitsk=# \d+ skill_skill
                      Table "public.skill_skill"
  Column   |  Type  | Modifiers | Storage | Stats target | Description
-----------+--------+-----------+---------+--------------+-------------
 skill1_id | bigint | not null  | plain   |              |
 skill2_id | bigint | not null  | plain   |              |
 count     | bigint | not null  | plain   |              |
Foreign-key constraints:
    "skill_skill_skill1_fk" FOREIGN KEY (skill1_id) REFERENCES skill(skill_id)
    "skill_skill_skill2_fk" FOREIGN KEY (skill2_id) REFERENCES skill(skill_id)
```

**Approximate Row Count of Table Being Queried**

```
cotitsk=# SELECT reltuples::bigint AS estimate FROM pg_class where relname='skill_skill';
 estimate
-----------
 435104320
(1 row)
```

**Explain Analyze**

```
cotitsk=# explain analyze select * from skill_skill where skill1_id = '2701941' order by count desc limit 1000;
                                                                QUERY PLAN
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=8228458.83..8228461.33 rows=1000 width=24) (actual time=37163.205..37163.600 rows=1000 loops=1)
   ->  Sort  (cost=8228458.83..8229292.78 rows=333580 width=24) (actual time=37163.203..37163.394 rows=1000 loops=1)
         Sort Key: count DESC
         Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 127kB
         ->  Seq Scan on skill_skill  (cost=0.00..8210169.00 rows=333580 width=24) (actual time=14021.081..37128.913 rows=210902 loops=1)
               Filter: (skill1_id = '2701941'::bigint)
               Rows Removed by Filter: 434893298
 Planning time: 0.062 ms
 Execution time: 37163.747 ms
(9 rows)
```

**Postgresql.conf**

```
max_connections = 1000
shared_buffers = 16GB
work_mem = 100MB
maintenance_work_mem = 1GB
dynamic_shared_memory_type = posix
wal_buffers = 16MB
effective_cache_size = 48GB
logging_collector = on
log_filename = 'postgresql-%a.log'
log_truncate_on_rotation = on
log_rotation_age = 1d
log_rotation_size = 0
log_timezone = 'UTC'
```

Comment: To my untrained Postgres eye, I would venture to guess that an index on `skill1_id` would help here.

Comment: It seems that adding some primary keys might be needed. (and maybe FKs, and maybe additional indexes) Asl: the skill_id seems to me an bigint, not a text field: `where skill1_id = '2701941'` -->> `where skill1_id = 2701941`

Comment: @JNevill There is a foreign key on `skill1_id`, I guess this is an index as well (not sure though). What might help additionally is a combined index on `(skill1_id, count)`

Comment: I'm an idiot, I thought I had created an index on the table, but turns out I had not. Creating an index sped the query up to a completely acceptable response time. Thanks, and sorry for wasting time.